# Android unit tests can't find Mockito package

Tags: android-studio, classpath, mockito, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio with Gradle, and I am trying to use Mockito in my unit tests. The problem is that I receive the following errors when I run the tests:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Error:(9, 19) error: package org.mockito does not exist
>
> Error:(11, 26) error: package org.mockito does not exist
>
> Error:(19, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable MockitoAnnotations

My `build.gradle` file is nothing more than the default with the Mockito dependencies added:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // These are the only lines I added:

    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Then, the lines in my code that are causing the error are just these imports:

```
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

---

The explanations I've found online all say that the .jar is missing from the CLASSPATH. As far as I understand, Gradle should automatically add the dependencies to the CLASSPATH. Is this correct?

Just to make sure I didn't have to add the jar manually, I also attempted updating the CLASSPATH in my `.bashrc` file, but this did not work:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/myusername/my/jar/path/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I figured out that if I change `androidTestCompile` to just `compile`, everything works fine. I'm not sure if this is the correct usage though. Am I just completely misunderstanding the purpose of `androidTestCompile`?

Comment: Be careful since compile will include mockito into your apk. Which is not your intention I think

Comment: What kind of unit tests you have - robolectric or Instrumental?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to run your unit tests with mockito in gradle, the right way to add it to your `build.gradle` file is:

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

Note that it is `testCompile` and not `androidTestCompile`

With `androidTestCompile` you are making mockito available for Android instrumentation tests, not for unit tests.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks. Just a little update: Use `testImplementation` instead of `testCompile`.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same issue I faced when I was using "release" build type. Try to switch to the "debug".

Comment: Because of the Mockito dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several different approaches to installing Mockito, following the advice of several sites, but continued to have errors with Gradle build or the test build.  I should note that my Android Studio version is `0.6.1`. Here is what finally worked for me:

I downloaded the jar files myself and added them to a package in my project structure: `../app/libs`:

- dexmaker-1.0.jar
- dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar
- mockito-all-1.9.5.jar

Then I went to `File> Project Structure...`  and clicked on the `Dependencies tab`.

From here I could add File dependencies for each of the three jar files.  Once added, I changed the Scope to Test compile to prevent them from being included in my APK. After a Gradle Sync, and a Project Clean, I was able to mock classes without issue.

This approach may be a bit more manual than others, but in the end was much simpler than any of the other suggestions I was able to find.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was a pretty simple fix;

You may need to synchronize the gradle dependencies.

On the bar to the right you'll see the gradle tool bar *(If not you find it under `View > Tools Window > Gradle` in the top menu bar)*. Click the [image: refresh] symbol and it will download it for you.